# Windows 10 not installing from boot camp

Tags: windows

[image]This is really worrying me as I need this computer to function by tomorrow.

So, I downloaded Windows 10 and loaded it onto my computer, and now it keeps saying that "An unexpected error occurred and Windows could not install, press 'OK' to retry". This has been looping for over 20 mins. I desperately need help.

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac? What version of macOS are you using? Can you boot back to macOS? Can you post the output from the Terminal application command `diskutil list`? You can edit your question and include this information. You will need to post a comment so I can be informed you updated your question. You should include an @David somewhere in your comment.

Comment: @David No, I cannot run any apps, and no, i cannot boot back . The model is the latest desktop made by Apple. I am using Sierra. I will include a picture of the screen.

Comment: Well if Windows is not going to install, then you have no choice other than to press the power button until the Mac shuts off. When turning the Mac back on, you may have to hold down the option key until the Startup Manager icons appear.  Select to boot back to macOS.

Comment: You may want to goto the Startup Disk pane in the System Preferences application and make sure your macOS volume is highlighted. This will make the Mac automatically boot to macOS on startup and restart.